# Eliminar contacto en agenda telefónica

Tags: c++, c++11, dev-c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
```

Esta es la libreria quee utilicé

```
struct Agenda{

    int id;
    char nombre[30];
    char telefono[10];
    char direccion[20];
}a[10]; 
int index=0;
```

Estos son los datos que estoy pidiendo en mi agenda, lo normal.

```
void Alta()
{
    cout<<"Ingrese id: "<<endl;
    cin>>a[index].id;
    cout<<"Ingrese nombre: "<<endl;
    cin>>a[index].nombre;
    cout<<"Ingrese telefono: "<<endl;
    cin>>a[index].telefono;
    cout<<"Ingrese direccion: "<<endl;
    cin>>a[index].direccion;

    index++;
}
```

El prototipo para poder dar de alta al contacto funciona sin ningún problema, lo guarda correctamente.

```
int buscar(int cve)
{
    int x=0, pos=0;
    int ban=0;
    while(x<10 && ban==0)
    {
        if(cve == a[x].id)
        {
            ban= 1;
            pos=x;
        }
        x++;
    }
    return pos;
}
```

Para buscar un contacto también funciona bien, pide el ID para poder buscar un contacto que ya se haya guardado. Con esa no tengo problema.

```
void mostrar(int pos)
{
    cout<<"ID: "<<a[pos].id<<endl;
    cout<<"Nombre: "<<a[pos].nombre<<endl;
    cout<<"telefono: "<<a[pos].telefono<<endl;
    cout<<"Direccion: "<<a[pos].direccion<<endl;
}
```

Con la opción de mostrar funciona bien, solicito el numero ID, para poder localizar al contacto con ese id.

```
void eliminar()
{
    int elim=0;
    int i,res,k;
    int op,vr;
    do{
        cout<<"Ingrese el ID que desea elminar: "<<endl;
        cin>>op;
        for(i=0;i<elim;i++){
            if(op==a[index].id)
            {
                cout<<"ID: "<<a[index].id<<endl;
                cout<<"Nombre: "<<a[index].nombre<<endl;
                cout<<"Telefono: "<<a[index].telefono<<endl;
                cout<<"Direccion: "<<a[index].direccion<<endl;

                i=vr;
                do
                {
                    cout<<"Esta seguro de eliminar el contacto? 1:Si  2:No"<<endl;
                    cin>>res;
                    if(res<1 || res>2)
                    {
                        cout<<"Error, intente de nuevo"<<endl;
                        system("pause");
                        system("cls");
                    }//fin if
                    else{
                        a[vr].id=0;
                    }//fin else
                }while(res<1 || res>2);
                system("cls");
                break;
            }
        }//fin del for
    }while(k==1);
}
```

Esto es lo que realicé para poder ELIMINAR un contacto de los que ya he dado de alto, en está si valide los errores, para también poder comprobar si el contacto se eliminaba y también para ver si el prototipo funciona. Cuando corro el programa, doy de alta unos contactos, a la hora de dar la opción de eliminar, solamente me pregunta que cual ID deseo eliminar, y después no sucede nada. No se que pueda estar mal dentro del código que no lo está dejando funcionar

```
int main()
{
    int opc=0, cve=0;

    do{
        system("cls");
        cout<<"MENU"<<endl;
        cout<<"1.- ALTA "<<endl;
        cout<<"2.- BUSCAR "<<endl;
        cout<<"3.- EDITAR "<<endl;
        cout<<"4.- REMOVER "<<endl;
        cout<<"5.- MOSTRAR "<<endl;
        cout<<"SELECCIONA OPCION: "<<endl;
        cin>>opc;

        switch(opc)
        {
            case 1: 
                Alta();
                break;
            case 2:
                {
                    cout<<"Ingrese ID: "<<endl;
                    cin>>cve;
                    mostrar(buscar(cve));
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                eliminar();
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
        }
        cout<<"Continuar [1], Salir[3]";
        cin>>opc;

    } while(opc!=2);
    system("Pause>>cls");
    return 0;
}//Fin main
```

Por ultimo esta el menú con sus opciones y donde llamo a las funciones

[image: Esto es lo que sucede con la opción 4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

- Tu función `buscar( )`:
  Si no encuentra un contacto, devuelve `0`. Lo cual coincide con localizar un contacto en la posición `0`. Deberías retornar un valor *especial* en caso de no encontrar el `id`. Además, una vez encontrado ... ¿ Para que seguir buscando ?

  ```
  int buscar( int cve ) {
    for( int idx = 0; idx < 10; ++idx ) {
      if( a[idx].id == cve ) { return idx; }
    }

    return -1;
  }
  ```
- Tu función `Alta( )` **siempre** utiliza el siguiente `index` disponible ... lo cual te impide reutilizar *huecos*. Es decir, una vez introducidos 10 contactos, aunque borres uno, no podrás introducir mas.
- Tu función `mostrar( )` **no tiene en cuenta** que los elementos se pueden eliminar:

  ```
  void mostrar( int pos ) {
    if( a[pos].id == -1 ) { return; }

    cout << "ID: " << a[pos].id;
    cout << "\nNombre: " << a[pos].nombre;
    cout << "\ntelefono: " << a[pos].telefono;
    cout << "\nDireccion: " << a[pos].direccion << '\n';
  }
  ```
- Tu función `eliminar( )`:

  ```
  void eliminar()
  {
      int elim=0;
      int i,res,k;
      int op,vr;
      do{
          cout<<"Ingrese el ID que desea elminar: "<<endl;
          cin>>op;
          for(i=0;i<elim;i++){
  ```

  Si `elim = 0`, **nunca** va ha entrar en tu bucle `for( )`. `i = 0; i < elim` **no se cumplirá nunca** y la ejecución salta el `for( )`.

  De todas formas, ¿ Porqué no usas el resto de funciones que ya tienes ?

  ```
  void eliminar( ) {
    int posToErase;

    do {
      int idToErase;

      cout << "Ingrese el ID que desea elminar:\n";

      cin >> idToErase;

      posToErase = buscar( idToErase );

      if( posToErase == -1 ) { cout << "Error: ID no encontrado.\b"; }
    } while( posToErase == -1 );

    mostrar( posToErase );

    char response;

    do {
      cin.ignore( );
      cout << "Esta seguro de eliminar el contacto ? (s)/(n)\n";
      cin >> response;
    } while( ( response != 'n' ) && ( response != 's' ) );

    if( response == 's' ) {
      a[posToErase].id = -1;
      cout << "Eliminado.\n";
    } else {
      cout << "Cancelado.\n";
    }
  }
  ```